# Printing the correct amount of decimal places? (printf) - JAVA

Tags: java, printing, format

I'm trying to give back to the community a bit more...

Let's say x, my double variable, sometimes has different amounts of decimal places. (Ex. 1.2, 1.23, 1.234) But I only want to printf the minimum amount of decimal places that the variable has, without all those 0s at the end. How do I do that?

Comment: And what was wrong with `double x = 2.10; System.out.println(x);`?

Comment: Or if using `printf()`, use `%s` instead of `%f`.

Comment: I already had everything in a `System.out.printf();` so I wanted to keep it like that. :P @ElliottFrisch Plus, this should have more uses, such as drawing a string to a JFrame that you can't format when appending text.

Comment: Try your code with `double x = 0.05 + 0.05 + 0.05;`

Comment: hmm... Is it working for you? That seems weird to me... Any explanation? You're much better at this than I am, might as well try to soak up some knowledge :D @ElliottFrisch

Comment: This is very weird, when I try `double x = 0.05 + 0.05 + 0.05; System.out.println(x);` the console prints `0.15000000000000002` What's that about? @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Floating point can't accurately represent every number. For example, what is `0.05` in base 2?

Comment: hmmm then why does it print like that if it's a double? @ElliottFrisch would I have to do some casing to get the correct output? `EDIT:` ahhh yes it was!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with (it's too simple, no credit needed):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  double x = 100.512f;

  //no decimal places
  if (x % 1 == 0) {
    System.out.printf("x = %.0f", (float) x);
    //one decimal place
  } else if ((x * 10) % 1 == 0) {
    System.out.printf("x = %.1f", (float) x);
    //two decimal places
  } else if ((x * 100) % 1 == 0) {
    System.out.printf("x = %.2f", (float) x);
    //three decimal places
  } else if ((x * 1000) % 1 == 0) {
    System.out.printf("x = %.3f", (float) x);
  }
  //and so on...
}
```

Comment: You will never be able to do the above successfully. For example, what should the output be for x=0.1502?  for x=0.15002 ? for .01500002 ? for 0.15000000000000002 ? How can you distinguish that from what you wanted from x=.05+.05+.05, since their internal representations are identical?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use double only? BigDecimal can be used with scale set so that it displays only the required number of decimal places.